# Promoted Links - Menu

Tags: menu

How can I add multiple links under one Promoted links tile?
Eg. Tile 1 - Company
              - Link 1 - About Us
              - Link 2 - Leadership
              - Link 3 - Contact Us

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do that in the default app by changing settings or metadata. You would have to add CSOM code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Modern web pages do not support editing the html source like classic pages. The modern web parts have customization options displayed in the panel on the right, but those are the sum total of the customization options. So, promoted links will show one link per tile. If you want a customized version of this, then a custom web part can be created via SPFx (warning, this requires a developer level skill set).